# (block chain marbles sample) Error: Missing parameter. Must have a username

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am new to block chain and hyperledger-fabric, I am trying to setup Marbles sample application. I followed tutorial
[Use Local Hyperledger Network](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/docs/use_local_hyperledger.md)

While executing this command (node enrollAdmin.js) i got following error.

- Node version : v6.2.1
- Npm Version : 3.9.3
- Docker Version: 18.03.1-ce

  $ node enrollAdmin.js

  Store path:/opt/blockchain/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
  Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"
  error: [Client.js]: Error: Missing parameter. Must have a username.
  at _setUserFromConfig (/opt/blockchain/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1280:27)
  at Promise (/opt/blockchain/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1432:11)
  at setUserContext (/opt/blockchain/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1413:10)
  at promise.then.then.then.then (/opt/blockchain/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1692:17)
  Error: Failed to load key or certificate and save to local stores.
  at promise.then.then.then.then.then.catch (/opt/blockchain/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1702:19)
  Failed to enroll admin: Error: Failed to enroll admin

Could anyone help me to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it got worked when i ran following command

```
$ sudo node enrollAdmin.js
```